# Devise NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#create for email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My Rails 4.2 app uses devise for authentication but it's intended to not use a user's email so there's no SQL column for email. So I went into `/config/intializers/devise.rb` and changed the file to `config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]`. Unfortunately when I try to hit the `POST localhost:3000/users` endpoint which should direct to `Devise::Registrations#create`, I get this response:

[image]

[image]

My app doesn't need any HTML templates since it's intended to just be an API. Using `byebug`, I can see that none of the code I wrote is hit. Here is what I have so far:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # POST /resource
  def create
    byebug
    super

    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json do
          render json: @user, serializer: UserLoginSerializer
        end
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json do
          render status: :unprocessable_entity, json: {
            error: "Invalid Parameters for User Creation"
          }
        end
      end
  end

  # protected

  # You can put the params you want to permit in the empty array.
    def configure_sign_up_params
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :platform
    end
end
```

How can I bypass this error without creating the useless extra `:email` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops I forgot to specify my controllers in `routes.rb`. You have to do:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: "users/registrations",
    sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }
```

I had thought `devise_for :users` was sufficient.